# Token Auth with AngularJS and Rails, can't get access token from request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, request-headers

I setup token authentication with Angular and Rails following this tutorial: https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the `current_user` helper provided by the `devise_token_auth` gem. Even when a user is successfully authenticated through Angular (using `ng-token-auth`), `current_user` always returns `false` in Rails. According to `devise_token_auth`'s documentation (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth), "The authentication information should be included by the client in the headers of each request". These would be 'access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', and 'client'.

What I think my problem is: I can see those auth headers in the network tab of my web inspector when at http://localhost:3000/#/whatever (angular/client side), but at http://localhost:3000/api/whatever (rails/server side), the auth headers aren't there. Therefore `request.headers['access-token']` for example, would return nil.

I read through similar/same issues a couple places, mainly here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/74 , but no success yet.

I don't usually ask very many questions so hopefully this makes sense. Also, I'm brand spankin' new to Angular and have only been in the Rails game for a couple years, so if this is the dumb question... my bad ;)

Comment: Does the initial sign-in seem to work as expected? If so, is ng-token-auth sending a request to the `tokenValidationPath` on each request? Does it return a 200?

Comment: @JasonSwett Initial sign-in seems to work. The request URL for each request  has `http://localhost:9000/api/whatever` with status of 200. I'm not seeing the `tokenValidationPath` (which is set to the default path `'/auth/validate_token'`)

Comment: Can you post the headers and payload being sent with your request and then the output of the Rails log for that request?